# How to fix a FlexBox issue in the Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

FlexBox blocks in the IE11
[image]

In other browsers:
[image]

https://uzinouzi.github.io/testtemplate/  - link to site.

Comment: I don't have an IE browser right now to test, but you should try setting a width or min-width.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy, for what?

Comment: To the `information__about-us-items` class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi did you ever get this issue figured out?  I'm running into the exact same problem with IE11 and flexbox.

Answer (score -2):

Use prefixes

```
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

this site help you to know browsers support to property

Comment: Check my site, i use that prefixes